# Scala Dispatch Set content-Length

Tags: scala, dispatch-scala

I have an http post call with dispatch like this,

```
 url(API_HOST + URL).POST <:<
          headers <:<
          Map("Content-Type" -> "application/x-www-form-urlencoded") <<
          "name=SomeName&parentId=SomeParentID"
```

To add the Content-Lenght, what is the correct way of calculating the bytes,

```
Map("Content-Length" -> string.getBytes("UTF-8").length()toString)
```

I'm not sure if this should work, or is setted by default form dispatch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't need to add the content lengt this is added by the underlying librarie, the only thing that you must do is add the content:

```
 url(API_HOST_URL).POST <:<
otherheadersAsMAp <:<
Map("Content-Type" -> "application/x-www-form-urlencoded") << 
"name=SomeName&parentId=SomeParentID"
```